# How to filter variable query in grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

i am using Prometheus as a data source to display metrics in a Grafana dashboard. I want to filter variables to return me specific outputs. I am not sure if i should use Regex or the filtering is supposed to be within the query itself . Here is the output that i get :

[image: Variable output]

i only want it to return me services that include "waves" because i'm willing to add other services to my data source.

I've tried these queries but all of them whether returns me None or an error

`label_values(service{service=~"^waves$"}, service)`

`label_values(service{service="waves"}, service)`

`label_values(service{service=~"waves"}, service)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any tangible difference whether this will be accomplished with filtering on Prometheus' side or on Grafana's.

Filtering on Prometheus will result in slightly less data transferred, but difference is negligible.

Regarding your query: you are using regex selector in a wrong way. Your selector **must** match whole value of the label. So your query should look like this:

```
label_values(service{service=~".*waves.*"}, service)
```

---

Additionally, I would recommend you to look into [Prometheus' naming best practices](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/). Maybe consider changing your metric to something like `mysystem_service_info{name="..."}`

Comment: I managed to find a solution. It's by using Regex.
I simply added /^waves/ within Regex field and it worked.

Comment: Yes, it is the alternative: you request all metrics, and then filter them on Grafana's side. @yosribhiri

Comment: @yosribhiri, feel free to post it as a separate answer.